# POST to two locations using AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, post

On a web page I have a button that does a POST to a server that I don't have anything to do with. When someone clicks the button, I need to update some data on my (another) server so that when the user is eventually redirected back, the correct info will be displayed. Is this something that AJAX can do?

Many thanks,
TA

Comment: Can you elaborate? A request can not hit 2 different URLs(of the same server;  and 2 different servers is a different thing altogether). May you would need one server to make a request to the second..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

With Jquery, it will be something like that:

```
 var url1 = $.post("url1", {...});
 var url2 = $.post("url2", {...});

 $.when(url1, url2).then(function() {
      // Action when the two posts are back
 });
```

You can also act upon just one of the urls if the other one is not important.

Comment: The question doesn't mention jQuery at all. Besides (IMO), OP means he wants to hit 2 distinct servers in one HTTP request..

Comment: Jquery is just a tool, why does it matter if the question was asking about Jquery or not? Was it asking about pure XHR?

Comment: Thanks very much - Jquery is a good option in my case. (And it doesn't have to be in one HTTP request.)